# How can I make the text in a Picker's selection dialog wrap when too long?

Tags: c#, xamarin, combobox, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms, and the problem that I'm running into is wrapping text in the selection dialog.

I know I can change the appearance of the Picker itself using a custom renderer (which I have already done), but I can't figure out how to change the appearance/behavior of the selection dialog. Here's an example screenshot:

[image: Appearance of picker]

As you can see, the text on this last option is too long and stretches beyond the boundaries of the selection dialog. How can I get this text to wrap?

Comment: Can you please provide the code you're using to generate the UI? How can anyone debug this from a photo

Comment: @AnthonyRussell This is the default UI that appears when tapping on a Picker in Xamarin.Forms apps. I do not generate it anywhere, it's built-in.

Comment: Ehhh it's not magic. There is code in there somewhere generating the UI. If you can find that then you can find the attributes on the label that's being displayed. There's likely one that does textwrapping

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I realize that it's being generated *somewhere*, but I don't have access to that code. The best I can do to customize a built-in control is to use a custom renderer, but as my question explains, I can only find how to write a custom renderer for the Picker control itself, not the selection dialog. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: `PickerRenderer` for Android uses native `TextView` and `TextView` has `Ellipsize` property. I think, you could use it.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Ah, close... but I believe the TextView that is used by the Picker is the appearance of the Picker itself, not the dialog it spawns when tapped. After further research, it looks like the dialog it spawns is some variation of an AlertView class.

Comment: @MageXy Did you got a solution?

Comment: Did you get  any solution??

Comment: @EstebanChornet Kind of. I worked with some other devs at my place of work and ended up creating custom flyout that triggers when combo boxes are tapped in my app, along with unique display item classes. Unfortunately it is a proprietary to the company I work for so I cannot share the solution, as it was quite custom.